# parsing complex XML structure using NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, xml, nsdictionary, nsxmlparser

I have this fairly complex XML being returned from my server, I would like some help parsing it into a object I can acess for later use.

This is what the xml looks like

```
<Eng>
    <Result         >
        <Series         >
            <Link/>
            <FMF/>
                <AlsoLink/>
                <Plugins/>
            </FMF>
            <Sheet          >
                <Spaces>
                    <Spacing            >
                    <Names/>
                    </Spacing>
                    <Spacing            >
                    <Names/>
                    </Spacing>
                </Spaces>
            </Sheet>
        </Series>
    </Result>
</Eng>
```

I am then using NSXMLParser to try and parse all of the "ObjectForKey/s" of each element in the xml into their own dictionarys.. if that makes sense.

This is what my code is currently looking like

```
#pragma mark - Parsing lifecycle

- (void)startTheParsingProcess:(NSData *)parserData
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:parserData]; //parserData passed to NSXMLParser delegate which starts the parsing process
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse]; // starts the event-driven parsing operation.
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Series"]){
        parsedMutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:attributeDict];
        self.parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Link"]) {

        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"FMF"]) {
            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"AlsoLink"]) {

            }
            else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Plugins"]) {

            }
        }
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Sheet"]) {

            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Spaces"]) {

                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Spacing"]) {

                    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Names"]) {

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{    
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Series"]){
         [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries addObject:parsedMutableDictionary];

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Link"]) {

        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"FMF"]) {
            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"AlsoLink"]) {

            }
            else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Plugins"]) {

            }
        }
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Sheet"]) {

            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Spaces"]) {

                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Spacing"]) {

                    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Names"]) {

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }


//     parsedMutableDictionary = nil;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    NSLog(@"Paser Error = %@", parseError);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"A parsing failure occurred." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}


//TODO: Look into how to use this method over multiple views. i.e.(other requests such as keycode, advanced )
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    // display values
        NSArray *filteredArray = parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries;
        NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);

}
```

The problem I am having is that I dont understand what I should have in their own objects... also when some of these values return I could have multiple Spacing elements and I just dont know how to handle that...

Any help or tips would be hugely appreciated, if I havent specified something just ask as my brain is just struggling to wrap itself around this problem.

thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this is helpful, but, I'll just toss this out there and hopefully not get down voted - But, is there anyway you could change the output of the data from XML to JSON? Parsing JSON is a snap compred to XML.

Comment: unfortunatly not..I have to deal with what I am given thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your XML file....

```
<Series element1="something" element2="something">
    <Spaces>
         <Spacing>
              <Names>
                 Something
              </Names>
         </Spacing>
         <Spacing>
              <Names>Something</Names>
         </Spacing>
    </Spaces>
</Series>
```

To get the value of element1 you have to do.....

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{   
    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"Series"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"element1"]);
    }
}
```

To get the multiple values of Spacing you have to do....

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
       [currentSpacingName appendString:string];
       [currentSpacingName appendString:@"any character"]
    }
}
```

After that store the value into a dictionary with desire key in this method...

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

this is just an example i hope now you could solve your problem.

Comment: BOOM! this is exactly what I was hoping to see... I kind of came to this conclusion but was having trouble getting it into my head in an undestandable manner let alone construct it into a question for someone else to help me with... Okay I will continue on with this and try to get it up and running.. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using NSXMLParser.... so you will get the strings between the tag... `<tag>strings</tag>`

To get the multiple Spacing elements you can append all the strings in a NSString object..

Comment: yea, between my tags I have keys.. is that the correct work? elementone="1" elementtwo="2" etc. so I store them into a MutableDictionary then I put my mutableDictionary into an array... The thing I am confused with is the structure and multiple elements i.e. I have have multiple spacings... I cant get my head around how I should store them.